# how to print a dict which has japanese word using python 

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code :

```
import xlrd,sys
data = xlrd.open_workbook('a.xls')
boss = data.sheets()[3]
print boss.row_values(3)[1]
```

it can show the right word :

```
ｷｬﾌﾟｼｮﾝｻﾝﾌﾟﾙ。てすてす。改行もしたいよ
```

but because the a.xls has many data , so i append this data to a dict in python ,

like this :

```
stage_dict[stage_number]['boss'][boss_number]['name'] =  boss_row_list[4]
```

and show it :

```
print stage_dict
```

but it show this :

```
'\uff77\uff6c\uff8c\uff9f\uff7c\uff6e\uff9d\uff7b\uff9d\uff8c\uff9f\uff99\u3002\u3066\u3059\u3066\u3059\u3002\u6539\u884c\u3082\u3057\u305f\u3044\u3088\u3002'
```

so what can i do ,

how to print a dict using the right Coding,

thanks

**updated:**

this is a simple demo :

```
#coding:utf-8

a={0:"ｷｬﾌﾟｼｮﾝｻﾝﾌﾟﾙ。てすてす。改行もしたいよ"}
b="ｷｬﾌﾟｼｮﾝｻﾝﾌﾟﾙ。てすてす。改行もしたいよ"
print a,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive your own class from `dict` and override `__str__` method:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class MyDict(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{"+", ".join(["%s: %s" % (key, self[key]) for key in self])+"}" 

a = {0:"Velmi žluťoučký kůň"}
b = MyDict({0:"Velmi žluťoučký kůň"})
c = "Velmi žluťoučký kůň"
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
{0: 'Velmi \xc5\xbelu\xc5\xa5ou\xc4\x8dk\xc3\xbd k\xc5\xaf\xc5\x88'}
{0: Velmi žluťoučký kůň}
Velmi žluťoučký kůň
```

The derived class will behave exactly the same as `dict`, but it will print using the method you specify.

Comment: Similarly you could derive your own string class that has a custom '__repr__()' method. That would make strings of that type print properly everywhere, not just when they're in a `MyDict`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. `print(somedict)` will always print the `repr()` of the dict which is valid python code using escape sequences.

However, since printing a dict should be a debug-only thing anyway this is not really a problem. Displaying a value from the dict should work.

Answer (score 1):

Printing an object in Python will print how the object is represented in English text. Hence the result you are experiencing.

Comment: You could write your own function to print it your say or override an inbuilt method as someone else pointed out here.